# Generate multiple table of contents based on input to environment

Tags: table-of-contents, code

With the following (pseudo)-code

```
\newenvironment{A}[2]{\AddToToC{#1}{#2}}{}
\begin{A}{Test1}{1}
\end{A}
\begin{A}{Test2}{2}
\end{A}
\begin{A}{Test3}{1,2}
\end{A}
```

I want to generate the following output:

```
Table of Content 1:
Test1......1
Test3......1

Table of Content 2:
Test2......1
Test3......1
```

i.e. I have different ToCs, and I want to add the name of environment `A` to them in respect to the value given as second value when calling the environment. The value will be an integer number (but can be changed, if necessary).
An additional goody would be that I am able to include one environment into multiple ToCs (as in `Test3`), even if it is not implemented as in this draft. Is that possible?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you would post the document that needs this setup, especially the way how you generate multiple ToCs

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: The generation also is not done yet, my problem is the implementation of the function `\AddToToc{}{}`

Comment: Well, I can't see `\AddToToC` ;-) No code, no help, most likely

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: First line of my example (pseudo-)code: `\newenvironment{A}[2]{\AddToToC{#1}{#2}}{}`. I meant this function.

Comment: Well, this is not helpful. I guessed that you would use it this way, but what is `\AddToToc`???? That's why I asked about a document, not just fragments

Comment: That is a currently not-existing function, and the main aim for my question, to design that function.

Comment: Let it put me more clearly: 7 lines of code, unclear what is wanted -- that does not make this question clearly answerable. Why definining `\AddToToc` at all? What's wrong with `\addcontentsline` or `\addtocontents`?

Comment: I try to improve the question in order to make it more clearly.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: 50% done, will present results on monday...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Done, minor bugs, but the principle is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current draft (and possible solution for other cases, not for mine due to having too many `\writes`):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\AddToToCSingle}[2]{
    \refstepcounter{ToC#1%
    }
    \def\list{#1ToC}
    \def\listname{\list}
    \addcontentsline{\listname}{ToC#1}
    {\protect\numberline{\csname theToC#1\endcsname}#2}\par
}

\newcommand{\AddToToCMulti}[2]{
    \foreach\x in {#1}{\AddToToCSingle{\x}{#2}}
}

\newcommand{\PrintMultiToC}[1]{
    %\def\curToC{\expandafter\csname listofToC#1\endcsname}
    %\curToC
    \foreach\i in {#1}{\expandafter\csname listofToC\i \endcsname}
}

\newcommand{\GenerateMultiToc}[1]{
    \foreach\i in {#1}{%
        \newcommand\ToC{\expandafter\csname ToC\i\endcsname}
        \newlistof{ToC\i}{\i ToC}{\ToC\i}
        \expandafter\csname listofToC\i\endcsname
        }
}

\newcommand{\ToCA}{A}
\newlistof{ToCA}{AToC}{\ToCA}
\newcommand{\ToCB}{B}
\newlistof{ToCB}{BToC}{\ToCB}
\newcommand{\ToCC}{C}
\newlistof{ToCC}{CToC}{\ToCC}

\newenvironment{Test}[2]{\AddToToCMulti{#2}{#1}#1}{}

\begin{document}
    \PrintMultiToC{A,B}
    \GenerateMultiToc{F, G}
    %\PrintMultiToC{F,G}
    \begin{Test}{Hello}{A,G}
        World
    \end{Test}
\end{document}
```

The onliest thing which is currently not working is that I am not able to call `\PrintMultiToC{}` using my generated Lists, I have to print them directly in `\GenerateMultiToc{}`.